# How to use Comparator and Comparable in ArrayList?

Tags: java, algorithm, decision-tree

I need to sort the ArrayList with respect to column.That is In My ArrayList,each row contains some float values and a string.Each of them is separated using commas.

Example:

```
1 row:---  4.9,5.1,2.3,1.0,classA
```

likewise ALL ROWS.

So I want to sort this arraylist based on each values(based on the 1st val of all rows,similarly all rows).

Here How I use Comparator and Comparable?

Comment: What column are you talking about?

Comment: Do u mean you have an ArrayList of ArrayList??

Comment: Column in the sense,the values in each rows separated by comma.So take 1st value in all rows.And sort the arraylist based on that value.

Comment: @Dahlia - It doesn't work like that. In your ArrayList, do you have an object with float + String?. Or do you have some other data structure?

Comment: Not ArrayList of ArrayList.My Array List's each row contains many values, each one is separated by comma.So for example

Comment: What have you tried? The way SO works is you try your best to solve the problem, SHOW YOUR WORK, and ask a specific question.  We generally don't write the code for you.

Comment: 4.9,5.1,2.3,1.0,classA and 4.4,5.3,2.2,1.5,classB if these are rows.I want to sort it based on 1st value,that is 4.4,5.3,2.2,1.5,classB AND 4.9,5.1,2.3,1.0,classA.Next I want to sort based on IInd value in each row,that is 4.9,5.1,2.3,1.0,classA and 4.4,5.3,2.2,1.5,classB.Next I want to sort based on IIIrd value,that is 4.4,5.3,2.2,1.5,classB and 4.9,5.1,2.3,1.0,classA.Similarly up to second last value.

Comment: Do you mean you have an `ArrayList<String>`? Have you started anything?

Comment: The above example is my problem,it is not an ArrayList<ArrayList> form.It holds some float values in each row separated by comma.Just give a logic Not code.

Comment: @Dahlia, I don't understand what you have in your code.  What is the type of this `ArrayList`?  Is it `ArrayList<String>` or something else?  And do you have each line in one element of the `ArrayList` - or do you have each individual number in one element?  Without a bit more information, it's going to be very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). It will take your Array List and a Comparator.

You can create anonymous Comparator and in its compareTo method you will obtain that first value by splitting both the string and than compare them and return -1,0,1 accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class FieldComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private int column;
    private int numberOfFloats;

    public FieldComparator(int column, int numberOfFloats) {
        this.column = column;
        this.numberOfFloats = numberOfFloats;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String[] o1Fields = o1.split(",");
        String[] o2Fields = o2.split(",");
        if (column < numberOfFloats) {
            return new Float(o1Fields[column]).compareTo(new Float(o2Fields[column]));
        } else {
            return o1Fields[column].compareTo(o2Fields[column]);
        }
    }   
}
```

You can use instance of this class as `Comparator` while sorting or anything else.
Refer to documentation of `Comparator` and `Collections` for sorting.

Good luck.

Comment: java.lang.Float (and all other similar wrappers) has a static compareTo(float, float) method since java 1.4, and it should be really used instead of new Float.compareTo(new Float) idiom.